# Unable to build VTK examples

Tags: vtk

I'm having lots of difficulties just building VTK examples - can someone help please?

I've downloaded and installed VTK-9.0.1 on my ubuntu 18.04.4 system. Now I want to install and run [the VTK examples at this link.](https://github.com/lorensen/VTKExamples), so I clone that repo. Then I follow the instructions to ["Build all of the examples" at this link.](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Instructions/ForUsers#Build_all_of_the_examples). So I do this:

```
% mkdir VTKExamples-build
% cd VTKExamples-build
% cmake ../VTKExamples
```

cmake outputs these messages:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- VTKWikiExamples: Building VTKWikiExamples stand-alone
-- VTKWikiExamples: Building VTKWikiExamples stand-alone - yes
-- VTKWikiExamples: Setting executables prefix
-- VTKWikiExamples: Setting executables prefix - no
-- VTKWikiExamples: VTK VERSION: 9.0.1(OpenGL2)
-- VTKWikiExamples: Example executables are stored in /home/oreilly/VTKExamples-build/bin
-- VTKWikiExamples: Tests will not be built
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.0/vtkModule.cmake:2847 (message):
  No `MODULES` passed to `vtk_modules_autoinit`.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/Cxx/DataStructures/CMakeLists.txt:48 (vtk_module_autoinit)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.0/vtkModule.cmake:2847 (message):
  No `MODULES` passed to `vtk_modules_autoinit`.
  src/Cxx/DataStructures/CMakeLists.txt:48 (vtk_module_autoinit)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.0/vtkModule.cmake:2847 (message):
  No `MODULES` passed to `vtk_modules_autoinit`.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/Cxx/DataStructures/CMakeLists.txt:48 (vtk_module_autoinit)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.0/vtkModule.cmake:2847 (message):
  No `MODULES` passed to `vtk_modules_autoinit`.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/Cxx/DataStructures/CMakeLists.txt:48 (vtk_module_autoinit)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

The "No `MODULES` passed to `vtk_modules_autoinit`" error message is repeated over 400 times, and no Makefile is generated.

What am I doing wrong???
Thanks!

Comment: Did you get this one working?